# Can someone tell me the error, if exists, in this script?

Tags: php, dreamweaver

In dreamweaver I get the message:
'Syntax error on line 178. Code hinting may not work until you fix this error.'
This is the script code (line 178 is the one that starts with <?php if):

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    $(function ($) {
        var $nav = $("#thumb-slider");
        
        $nav.each(function () {
            $(this).owlCarousel2({
                nav:true,
                dots: false,
                slideBy: 1,
                margin:10,
                navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'],
                <?php if($direction=='rtl'):?> rtl:true, <?php endif;?>
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:2
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:3
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:4
                    }
                }
            });
        })
        
    });
//--></script>
```

Can anybody tell me what the syntax error is? Thanks

Comment: FYI, it hasn't been necessary to put JavaScript inside a comment for many years.

Comment: Does it work when you run the script? It looks OK to me, so it may just be a problem with DW.

Comment: Without firing up Dreamweaver, my first guess is that it doesn't like the PHP inside of JavaScript, and the HTML comment tag might further be freaking out that combination

Answer (score 0):

line 178 is php code

```php
    if($direction=='rtl')
```

however php variable $direction is not defined anywhere in scope. I've pasted your sample code into an online php engine ( [Repl.it - PHP](https://repl.it/languages/php_cli) ).

If in fact you have it defined further up your file, and the code runs ok, it may be a DW config issue, and you may need to configure DW such that the editor treats HTML files like PHP files . [Dreamweaver docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/dreamweaver/kb/change-add-recognized-file-extensions.html) give an example how to view or update your config (make a backup copy of files before editing)